# check date against an array of dates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to write a function that returns a TRUE or FALSE value based on whether the date is present in the array or not. Currently I have this:

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
    var a = array.indexOf(value) > -1;

    if (a == false) {
        return false; //DATE DOES NOT EXIST
    }
    else {
        return true; //DATE EXISTS IN ARRAY
    }
}
```

Now normally I would use a for loop, however I am generating a list of dates between a start date and end date with this while loop:

```
 while (day > 0) {
     var tDate = new Date(sDate.addDays(dayCounter));
     datesArray.push(tDate);
     day = day - 1; //DEDUCT THE DAYS AS ADDED

     var dateExists = isInArray(value, array);
     if (dateExists == false) {

     }
     else { 
         matchedDays++;
     }
     daysCounter++;
}
```

this however is not working and always returns FALSE, what do I need to do to make this work and return the correct value?

sample data: `ARRAY[26/12/2016, 27/12/2016, 28/12/2016, 29/12/2016]`

value passed in `[27/12/2016]`

- return TRUE  if the value exists in the array
- return FALSE if the value does not exist in the array

probably a simple mistake above! so thankyou for any help on this. also will a time affect the date when its being checked?

Comment: Is the date is store as a string in this array ?

Comment: By the way you can just return array.indexOf(value) > -1. No need to do that if else check. But are you sending both as strings or?

Comment: Hi, now, you can use includes.

Comment: the date is stored as a date element within the array

Comment: How you are passing the value to check? string or date object?

Comment: I am passing a date object, and the array is stored of date objects

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try using the [**`find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method (if ecmascript is supported):

#### Case: array contains strings

```js
var array = ["26/12/2016", "27/12/2016", "28/12/2016", "29/12/2016"];
var value1 = "26/12/2016";  //exists
var value2 = "26/12/2026";  //doesn't exist

function isInArray(array, value) {
  return (array.find(item => {return item == value}) || []).length > 0;
}

console.log(isInArray(array, value1));
console.log(isInArray(array, value2));
```

---

#### Case: array contains Date objects

```js
var array = [new Date("December 26, 2016 00:00:00"), new Date("December 27, 2016 00:00:00"), new Date("December 28, 2016 00:00:00"), new Date("December 29, 2016 00:00:00")];
var value1 = new Date("December 26, 2016 00:00:00");  //exists
var value2 = new Date("December 16, 2026 00:00:00");  //doesn't exist


function isInArray(array, value) {
  return !!array.find(item => {return item.getTime() == value.getTime()});
}

console.log(isInArray(array, value1));
console.log(isInArray(array, value2));
```

Comment: the function causes the application to crash before it even loads, it doesnt appear to like it

Comment: @Crezzer7 Yeah, I just realized you were working with Date objects and not strings. Sorry about that. Try my updated answer below.

Comment: its crashing after the => saying critical error, and thats when pressing debug on the application straight away

Comment: ahh my bad, i was passing the values in the wrong way around!!!! its been a long day

Comment: no, I thought it would but still crashing at the same point, I have no idea why because it works fine using the snippet above

Comment: now it compiles but crashes as array doesnt support the method .find

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125120/discussion-between-chris-and-crezzer7).

Answer (score 2):

you can use includes function.

```
ri = ["26/12/2016", "27/12/2016", "28/12/2016", "29/12/2016"]; 
ri.includes("20/12/2016"); //False
ri.includes("26/12/2016"); //True
```

Alternative to IE
indexOf return the position of value.

```
var pos = ri.indexOf("26/12/2016"); // 0
var pos = ri.indexOf("20/12/2016"); // -1
var pos = ri.indexOf("27/12/2016"); // 1


if(pos > -1){ //is in array }
```

Comment: Im afraid this does not work, "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Comment: @Crezzer7 I add an alternative to IE. Includes not working because the browser is not supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: the alternative answer still returns a constant value of -1 in my while loop aswell :/

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (value == array[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

should work..
You may have to use different comparing operations though.

Answer (score -1):

I solved by getting only the first 15 characters in the dates, this is my snippet:

```
//get the first 15 characters of each date in my array (hdates)
for (i=0;i<hdates.length;i++){
  hdates[i]=hdates[i].toString().substring(0,15); //converts dates to 15 characters long strings
}

function highlight(date) {
  if(hdates.indexOf(date.toString().substring(0,15))>-1) { //converts my date element to compare, too
       return'ok';
    } else {
       return 'ko';
    }
}
```

if you don't want to alter your array, I'd suggest you to clone it and then convert the dates in 15 character long strings