# How to select spesific dates in WPforms

Tags: javascript

I managed to limit the days to only Wednesdays but I am unable to limit it to specific dates on these Wednesdays, like for example I want the user to only be able to pick 26th of August, 23rd of September, 21st of October and 18th of November.  I am not sure how to start with this type of limitation. Any suggestion?

```
function wpf_dev_limit_date_picker() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.wpforms_75 = window.wpforms_75 || {};
        window.wpforms_75.datepicker = {
            disableMobile: true,
            // Don't allow users to pick past dates
            minDate: new Date(),
            // Don't allow users to pick any day besdies Wednesday
            enable: [
                //[0-6 Sunday - Saturday]
                function(dateObj){
                    return dateObj.getDay() !== 0 && dateObj.getDay() !==1 && dateObj.getDay() !==2 && dateObj.getDay() !==4 && dateObj.getDay() !==5 && dateObj.getDay() !==6;
                }
            ]
            
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_dev_limit_date_picker' );
```

Comment: Have you tried something like creating and array and checking if dateObj exists?
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39899589/1418750